# Angular $watch command selecting undefined variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I have some HTML code in which I use angular to repeat radio inputs.

I created a plunkr showing the functionality that I have right now.

http://plnkr.co/edit/n5OZVlbiwToHsuvGN3QI

The repeating code binds to a variable which I need to capture into the top level scope. ($parent.selectedType and $parent.selectedSpecies)

The code displays correctly in the HTML document but the data binding from ng-model does not work.

Thus I've set up a $scope.$watch command like this:

```
  $scope.$watch('type.selected', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.type.selected.forEach(function (typeName) {
            if (typeName === newVal) {
                $scope.selectedType = $scope.type.selected;
            }
        });
    });
```

to watch for changes in the typeName variable and when it changes set $scope.selectedType to what I just selected in the radio buttons.

However, when I try to run this code I keep getting "type is undefined" even though the $scope.$watch part is *immedately* after type definition.

Why is type undefined when I try to $watch it?

edit: The issue was deeper - it comes from the fact that $scope.type.selected.forEach() is not a function that is recognized. forEach() should be a function though, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of logic errors, here it is cleaned up:

```
$scope.$watch('type.selected', function (newVal, oldVal, $scope) {
    if ($scope.type.selected) {
        angular.forEach($scope.type.selected, function (value, typeName) {
            if (typeName === newVal) {
                $scope.selectedType = $scope.type.selected;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see there is a function being passed into the `forEach`. I believe this is where your issue is. Also I don't think the 3rd parameter of a `$watch` is `$scope`.

Comment: Yes, it cleaned the code up quite a bit. However, it's still telling me that $scope.type is undefined even though I define it just above. Why does that happen?

Comment: Should not be possible, can you fix up your plunkr so it runs and spits out the error you're describing?

Comment: I updated my original post with the error @MathewBerg.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!